# 'Return' keyword returns only one element from a loop?

Tags: python, return

I have a simple function to read the csv file and extracts the first coloum from it:

```
import csv 

def pass_username():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in spamreader:
            return row[0]
```

When I call this function as:

```
a = pass_username()
print a
```

This only prints the first element. However, when I replace `return` word with `print` as `print row[0]` and call the function as `pass_username()` it prints all the elements. I want to assign that function to a variable thus I want to use return. How to fix it?

Content of test.csv:

```
"test@gmail.com","rockon"
"hello@gmail.com","hey"
"hithere@gmail.com","ok"
"hellosir@gmail.com","password"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other people who answered said, you can accumulate the results into a list and return that. Another way though, would be to replace `return` with `yield` which causes your function to return an iterable type object that produces the items you yield when you decide to iterate over it later (possibly with a for loop).

See: [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Here is how you would use it with your code:

```
import csv 

def pass_username():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in spamreader:
            yield row[0]

username_generator = pass_username()

# iterate through the usernames with a for loop
for name in username_generator:
    print name
# call the list constructor which causes it to produce all of the names
print list(pass_username())
```

Keep in mind that the usernames are produced *as they are needed*, so you can, for example, do `username_generator.next()` which will produce the next username without having to produce all of them.

Comment: +1 one for mentioning a generator. Though the iterable type doesn't really "contain" the items because they are yielded on demand and not actually stored.

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult to explain exactly how it works without bringing up lazy evaluation and such. I'll edit my answer to better reflect that.

Comment: Might want to add a snippet of example code -- using is generators much easier than understanding them :)

Comment: It returns the generator object. How can I yield all the elements?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `return`, it autimtically exits out of the function, so it doesn't process anything after it reaches the `return` statement.

You might want to `append` the result to a list, then `return` the list.

In your case, you might even want to use a `list comprehension`, so instead of the for loop, use this:

```
return [row[0] for row in spamreader]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only return once from a function.  When it returns, it's over.  The first time your function returns, it ends, so it only returns one value.

If you want to return all the values, accumulate them into a list and return the list.

Comment: 'tis very annoying when you write an answer, and somebody else writes the exact same thing and submits his answer before you.